# apache Web server with raspberry not accessible from other devices

Tags: apache, raspbian

Before I was able to access my Apache default page on my raspberry from other devices.
Now it won't work anymore, and I have no idea how I can debug this.

When I access from my raspberry pi with its own ip address it works. But from my other device, I have a blank page. Like if port 80 was unaccessible; But that don't explain why it works from the local.

What is strange is that I have another server on another port (a flask web server), and this one is accessible with all the other device.

Is anyone have an idea?

**Edit**

I though apache was working, but after some debug, i thought out that it was lighttpd who was listening on port 80 and not letting Apache access it. I thought Apache was working because I could access to my server web (never though it was because of lighted autorunning). So I kicked lighttpd and restarted Apache, and now it works like a charm.

Comment: That's hard to say. The log files may tell you something in /var/log/apache2. If not, it could be iptables..

Comment: Yes, it is certainly the iptable. I have added some rules, but after that , I have deleted them. But when I list the iptable rules, the list is empty. By the way, I don't have any apache log on the path you suggested